# Svn CLI cannot connect to repo, but TortoiseSVN inside Wine and CLI on other Computer in same network *can*

Tags: svn

*[I hope this is the right StackExchange network for this, was not sure whether this belongs more here or in the Unix+Linux one]*

Previously, I was simply using the svn CLI on my linux laptop, everything worked fine. Now that I migrated
to a new desktop linux machine (same Arch Linux distribution, copied over all config files), it suddenly refuses to connect.
Weird thing is

1. I still can connect with my old laptop from within the same wifi network
2. on the new machine, svn CLI wont work but TortoiseSVN (inside wine) *does* work!

I am running out of ideas what could be the cause of this. I asked our SVN server admin if he had an idea
but he was clueless, too. I am apparently the only one with this problem.

### Some detail:

The command

```bash
svn list https://svn.OUR.DOMAIN/svn/REPO/trunks/OURTRUNK
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://svn.OUR.DOMAIN/svn/REPO/trunks/OURTRUNK'
svn: E000111: Error running context: Connection refused
```

same with `checkout` or anything else, really. Trying `http` gives me `Redirecting to URL 'https://svn.....` and then the same error message.
I'm kind of clueless what this means, I find the SVN docs hard to search and google-ing doesnt yield anything either.

I tried deleting my configuration in `$HOME/.subversion` to see if that would be the
cause of the problem, but same result.

my `/etc/hosts` does not have anything related in there, I don't have any entry in `.netrc` (I think that would be related? not sure). I also can get the server IPv4/6 via `host svn.OUR.DOMAIN`

Does anyone have a clue? Any obvious place that I am missing and should be looking at for a root cause?

Comment: Can you try to open the same URL (`https://svn.OUR.DOMAIN/svn/REPO/trunks/OURTRUNK`) not with "svn list" but with HTTP client, e.g. curl, wget, or even Firefox from the affected box? What happens on the server (see access logs), what's different between your client and other client which works? Also you can try to capture traffic to find out what's really going there.

Comment: yes i can access it with both wget and browser. the clients are equal, same version too on both machines. i need to see if i can get some server logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was an IPv6 issue!

When doing a `curl -vvvv https://svn.OUR.DOMAIN/.....`, I got

```
 * connect to SOME_IPV6_ADDR port 443 failed: Connection refused
 *   Trying SOME_IPV4_ADDR...
 * Connected to svn.OUR.DOMAIN (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX) port 443
```

so putting the ipv4 address into `/etc/hosts` like

```
XXX.XX.XX.XXX svn.OUR.DOMAIN
```

fixed the issue!

Comment: Fix the underlying issue - Rother disable ipv6 or support it properly. Otherwise you'll face the same problem in another service next month.